# Libreoffice Calc: convert many cells with text to numbers

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have got many cells in my file whose content is of the form

```
'14.05
```

I want to mass convert these cells, which contain text, to numbers, which I can compute with.

```
14.05
```

Is there a build-in function in Libre Office for such mass conversion, or do I need to fumble around with a macro?

Comment: Mass conversion possible, which solutions did you try when you searched the Internet for "calc text to number conversion"?

Comment: I googled and did not find anything. The closest thing I found relates to OpenOffice. https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Transforming_text-formatted_numbers_into_numbers This, however, doesn't change anything at all.

Comment: When you search for "calc text to number conversion" try the neooffice solutions, its ok that it isn't strictly named LibreOffice , because many of these Open Source projects are forks of OpenOffice anyway so worth a try

Comment: Also the OpenOffice solution you tried, works for me and I am using LibreOffice 5.2.7.2 . What version are you using, maybe it is a version issue, go to Help, About LibreOffice, what version does it say?

Comment: You need to use Find and Replace to remove the `'`. 
 https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/1843/changing-text-to-numbers/?answer=68235#post-id-68235.  Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125504/libreoffice-calc-how-to-convert-unformatted-text-to-numbers-or-other-format

Comment: stumbling across the same issue. flabbergasting how bad LO is.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If that apostrophe is a quote prefix rather than really cell content like so:

[image]

(note the apostrophe is only shown in formula bar but not in the cell)

then the following will be possible:

Select the whole column `A`. Then select `Data` - `Text to columns` from the menu bar:

[image]

Then click `OK`. Now all the content which looks like numbers will be converted to numeric.

The above works when dot is set as the decimal separator in your `Calc`. If you are using different locale settings where comma ist set as decimal separator, then `14.05` will never treated as numeric. Then only `14,05` will be treated as numeric.

Comment: doesn't work... a cell containing `18.9` is never changed

Comment: @axd: It works. Maybe your `Calc` uses different locale settings where comma ist set as decimal separator. Then `18.9` will never treated as numeric. Then only `18,9` will be treated as numeric.

Comment: @axd in that case, you need to click in the dialog on the column header and select "US English"

Comment: This answer doesn't work for multiple columns.

Comment: This works, though probably not for multiple columns, as pointed out by J. Schmidt. But the Search/Replace trick with regular expression matching linked to by Jim K is more flexible and will work with any number of columns. Just search for ".*" and replace with "&", with the regular expression checkbox checked.

Answer (score 5):

Use Find and Replace to edit the data again, as explained at 
 https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/1843/changing-text-to-numbers/?answer=68235#post-id-68235.

> Put .* into 'Search For:' and & into 'Replace With:'

Then format the cells as numbers.

Related: [LibreOffice Calc: How to convert unformatted text to numbers (or other format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125504/libreoffice-calc-how-to-convert-unformatted-text-to-numbers-or-other-format)

Comment: Note to @skierpage who proposed an edit: It's true that the original answer was misleading, but it would have been better to add a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells.
Right click / format cells

Note what the format is currently selected to - not what you expected, I'm sure

Then, choose the Number format you wish / enter

Select the cells once again

Menu / Data / Text to Columns

Be sure to select Trim spaces

/ Enter

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

"Text to Columns" works for one column only, not an array, so it may be tedious.

My problem was in importing a text (e.g., CSV) file with numbers.
Opening a CSV-file (e.g., TAB-separated) in Libre Calc makes text-formatted numbers ('3.14). Pasting the same information to an empty ods-file converts the numbers to type Number/General.

So, to convert a rectangle with 'numbers to numbers, mark your 'data, copy to a file (linux: cat > file.txt), open it in a suitable editor not destroying TABs, copy (or use xclip < file.txt if you have xclip installed), than paste to Libre Calc. An import dialog will appear - select TABs. You should have the decimal separator consistent with your locale.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say cell A1 contains:   `'14.05`
in cell A3 enter the following:

`=VALUE(REGEX(REGEX(A1; "\."; ","; "g"); "[^0-9,]"; ""; "g"))`

What happens is...
  1:  `REGEX(A1; "\."; ","; "g")`   converts all instances of dot "." to comma ","
  2:   `REGEX(xxx; "[^0-9,]"; ""; "g"))`   removes anything not a number or a comma.
  3:  finally `VALUE(xxx)`   converts the resulting string to a number.
(the formula works from the inside out)

The drawback here is that this particular suggestion works for one cell only so it has to be copied for each additional cell, maybe to a new column?
I try to avoid messing with formatting if possible. Having the innards sanitized first then tend to cosmetics usually pays off ;)